# Cannot find symbol error while creating objec of class in main

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my code.

I get an error saying:
variable ana of type Analyse
 cannot find symbol: ana.lesUlovligeOrd
 cannot find symbol: ana.sensurerTekst

Why?

```
import easyIO.*;   
import java.util.*; 

public class Eksamen {

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
    Analyse ana = new Analyse(); 
    ana.lesUlovligeOrd("sensurord.txt");
    ana.sensurerTekst("roman.txt", "sensurert-roman.txt"); 
    } 
} 


class Analyse { 

In tast = new In(); 
Out skjerm = new Out();


void lesUloveligeOrd(String s){ 
     }

void sensurerTekst(String s, String t){
         }
}
```

Comment: The method call `lesUlovligeOrd` (missing `e`) appears to be spelled differently than the method name: `lesUloveligeOrd`.

Comment: thanks! Really embarrassed right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you called `ana.lesUlovligeOrd("sensurord.txt");`

but actually `void lesUloveligeOrd(String s)` in Analyse class.

so you call like this `ana.lesUloveligeOrd("sensurord.txt");`

Comment: Thanks! A little embarrassed... When you've worked for hours with assignments your head gets really tired, and you don't spot little things like that :P